# Zune software won't work with keyboard pause and player button

Tags: keyboard, zune, zune-software

Can someone help me fix a problem where my Logitech keyboard won't work with the Zune software.

If I have nothing selected, the button will not work, or if the Zune software is on my other monitor as I play a game (full screen), it also won't work.  The buttons work if I have the Zune software selected or something like Mozilla.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no known solution for this; this problem is somewhat commonplace with multiple monitors, keyboard play/pause buttons, and media players like iTunes, Windows Media Player, and Zune software...